# With_Options not executing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module for validations and multiple types of products. In this module I would like to store the conditions for the MOCAP product type.

These validations should run only if product_type_mocap? is true. However they run even if it is false... Does anyone have any ideas why? I can give further details as necessary

```
module Validations
  module Product
    module Mocap
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        with_options if: :product_type_mocap? do |product|
          product.validates :length,
          :frame_rate_type,
          :biped,
          :loopable,
          presence: true
        end

        def product_type_mocap?
          product_type_id == 5
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried using it with a block argument for 'if' so that you can put a debugger into it?

Comment: but a debugger into the method itself, returns what it should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a different syntax? Or possibly a lambda for the `if`? e.g.

```
with_options presence: true, if: ->(obj) { obj.product_type_mocap? } do 
  validates :length, :frame_rate_type, :biped, :loopable
end
```

`with_options` will pass down the presence validator to each item and I find the lambda syntax works far more consistently than the symbol.